# can someone help me to know how to call a method in Angular having an id as parameter and make a ngIf?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, components, observable

Can someone helps me to know how to call a method returning data by a Id? that Id is a function parameter?
I am making a *ngFor. Each line has an id and anothers fields like:

```
 {
  id: 1,
  ...
 }
```

In my ts file, I have this method:

```
 getById(id:number){
    const activitepaabObj={
      activiteId: id
    }
    this.activitepaabService.activitepaabSelectBy(activitepaabObj)
      .subscribe(activitepaab=>{
        this.activitepaab= activitepaab
      })
  }
```

I want to call this method line by line through my *ngFor and make a condition(*ngIf) based on the data retourned the getById() method in my ".html" file.

my ".html" look like this.

```
<ul *ngfor= let item of mydata">
   
 <li *ngIf="this.getById(item.id)">{{item.id}}<</li>
   
</ul>
```

I want to the "li" to be viewed only when the length of the array (this.activitepaab) retourned by the "getById(id)"  is equal to 0.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: Try this `*ngIf="(getById(item.id) | async)"`

Comment: GetById doesn’t return an observable and calling this function from the template is really bad practise.